# How to replace null NAN or Infinite values to default value in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I'm reading in csvs into Spark and I'm setting the schema to all DecimalType(10,0) columns.  When I query the data, I get the following error:

```
NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN
```

If I have NaN/null/infinite values in my dataframe, I would like to set them to 0.  How do I do this?  This is how I'm attempting to load the data:

```
var cases = spark.read.option("header",false).
option("nanValue","0").
option("nullValue","0").
option("positiveInf","0").
option("negativeInf","0").
schema(schema).
csv(...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `NaN` values in multiple columns, you can use `na.fill()` to fill with the default value

example:

```
  val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    Seq((0f,0f, "2016-01-1"),
        (1f,1f, "2016-02-2"),
        (2f,2f, "2016-03-21"),
        (Float.NaN,Float.NaN, "2016-04-25"),
        (4f,4f, "2016-05-21"),
        (Float.NaN,Float.NaN, "2016-06-1"),
        (6f,6f, "2016-03-21"))
  ).toDF("id1", "id", "date")

data.na.fill(0).show
+---+---+----------+
|id1| id|      date|
+---+---+----------+
|0.0|0.0| 2016-01-1|
|1.0|1.0| 2016-02-2|
|2.0|2.0|      null|
|0.0|0.0|2016-04-25|
|4.0|4.0|2016-05-21|
|0.0|0.0| 2016-06-1|
|6.0|6.0|2016-03-21|
+---+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

My environment (using Spark 2.3.1 with Scala 2.11) doesn't replicate @ShankarKoirala answer - the `.na.fill()…` doesn't capture the `infinity` and `NaN`, because those are not empty values. However, walues could be tested using `.isin()` function:

```
val x1 = Seq((1.0, 1, "a"),(1.0, 1, "a"), (2.0, 2, "b")
           , (Float.NaN, 1, "a"), (Float.PositiveInfinity, 2, "a")
           , (Float.NegativeInfinity, 2, "a"))
        .toDF("Value", "Id", "Name")
x1
  .withColumn("IsItNull", $"Value".isNull)
  .withColumn("IsItBad", $"Value".isin(Double.NaN, Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.NegativeInfinity))
.show()
```

this will produce following results:

```
+---------+---+----+--------+-------+
|    Value| Id|Name|IsItNull|IsItBad|
+---------+---+----+--------+-------+
|      1.0|  1|   a|   false|  false|
|      1.0|  1|   a|   false|  false|
|      2.0|  2|   b|   false|  false|
|      NaN|  1|   a|   false|   true|
| Infinity|  2|   a|   false|   true|
|-Infinity|  2|   a|   false|   true|
+---------+---+----+--------+-------+
```

If a replacement is needed, just use original column name in the `withColumn()` function and apply the `.isin()` as argument of `when` function.

Comment: Can you please show replacement with an example, since its not clear how. It'll probably be too late for me to use but might help someone else.

Comment: @Jus12 `.withColumn("ValueWithReplacement", when($"Value".isin(Double.NaN, Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.NegativeInfinity), lit(0.0)).otherwise($"Value"))`

Answer (score 0):

you can set a single dataframe column to have 0 in places of NaN using the below expression. In this example any NaN values in column `col1` will be replaced with 0.

```
val df = (1 to 10).toDF("col1").withColumn("col1",when(when($"col1".isNull, 0).otherwise($"col1").isNaN, 0).otherwise($"col1"))
```